# Decay rate of a birth-death Markov chain and relationship with the support of the orthogonalizing probability

Tags: probability-distributions, stochastic-processes, markov-chains, markov-process

I am studying this [Article](https://pdf.sciencedirectassets.com/271499/1-s2.0-S0304414912X00048/1-s2.0-S0304414912000555/main.pdf?x-amz-security-token=FQoGZXIvYXdzEFYaDE9oCkpLbudx%2F6DwCyK3A6TFySGVgObQIpIE9Y6swnsFddLh8ag9OUCj8OSumY%2Fi5SG7rRGSzgDaN9BzpbmUmYDxVXHccgyhoLv7k7CWnRMluNSm5jwrGj7QcmDNEG08kojBDSQZwnLtDwZ%2FwLmk77cr1MKx2MMw3gju7q3yLAGByCMPj6pbQCt3lyPo37NJFjYhTdH%2FqodUZTD9dZc9dt1Il%2B8diRujMqTmkccbDhGchYhhhURminY8EA%2BNO364MtufWnZ8O0lmayf%2FPBEXsW%2BYtXzZ7gF5meUSKAMFfnqyfwB8eREMp%2BnL35hoGXQ7i8tvJ2AbgVcTO7TVThLlK%2FAszYBoVUc1k0%2B%2B0I29kgp8hI0cpjAyAfJ2RQODlyXwSASv6wEGmzmxxFK0hlkPFByq%2B2BNGp3ApufsqTMzprMI8x1IxVjTcuev3uXH3ymnPIQ8LkU0w%2FBS298Vq5tgofnVLmIKDqlYIMcxhNEJwa8k1hkQ4WfOY7XoQbwa1oqk3IJOERKX0IOdyfEwr0voO9EsNvD36Uq90Oo5cH4q9sW3j7tcCzG4v0l%2Bk8sx2LWNQr9sFDwdsQEFxQoQyET53iJEGOb2HJUo0Lfo5AU%3D&AWSAccessKeyId=ASIAQ3PHCVTY7J3FWCHQ&Expires=1553605637&Signature=ZrMr65M%2FLQOTPW8phNkB5n9cnlo%3D&hash=d55b44cef9f9eb1b99b2ace2ae8dbfb6171dafeab46b3d18ec06642fa3dc4633&host=68042c943591013ac2b2430a89b270f6af2c76d8dfd086a07176afe7c76c2c61&pii=S0304414912000555&tid=spdf-d6e8348d-97ff-4812-a66a-1128764456c8&sid=e033da9c97ed1141750baf6381400020fbe5gxrqb&type=client) by van Doorn on the existence of quasi-stationary distribution for a birth-death process with killing.

He defines the decay rate of a birth-death process with killing as
$$
\alpha =- \lim_{t\rightarrow \infty} \frac{1}{t} \log P_{ij}(t),
$$
where $P_{ij}(t)$ are the transition probabilities
$$
P_{ij}(t) = \mathbb{P} (X_t = j | X_0 = i).
$$
It can be shown that $\alpha$ is independent from $i,j$. 
Moreover there exists also an integral representation for the transition probability under suitable assumption on the process, namely the following one holds
$$
P_{ij}(t) = K_j \int_0^\infty e^{-xt}Q_{i-1}(x)Q_{j-1}(x)\psi(dx)
$$
where $\{ Q_n \}_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ is a orthogonal polynomial sequence given by the parameter of the process, that is not interesting for the question I am going to ask, anyway I underline that $Q_0 (x) = 1$. So that if $i=j=1$ we have that
$$
P_{11}(t) = \int_0^\infty e^{-xt} \psi(dx), \quad t \geq 0.
$$
Hence the author states that is an easy consequence of the integral representation of $P_{11}(t)$ that 
$$
\alpha = \inf \text{supp}( \psi).
$$
However I don't get why this would imply $\alpha$ to be the infimum of the support of $\psi$, any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Preparation:

- $\psi$ is a probability measure on $[0,\infty)$, because $1=P_{1,1}(0)= \psi([0,\infty))$.
- Recall that $x\in [0,\infty)$ is in the support of $\psi$ if and only if $\psi(U)>0$ for any neighborhood of $x$. Let $\beta = \inf \mbox{supp}(\psi)$.
- As a result,
  $$(*) \quad\psi\left( [0,\beta)\right)=0.$$

Fix $x$ in the support of $\psi$. Then

$$P_{1,1}(t) \ge \int_{(x-1/n,b+1/n)\cap[0,\infty)}e^{-xt} \psi(dx) \ge e^{-(x+1/n) t } \psi((x-\frac1n,x+\frac 1n)\cap [0,\infty)).$$

Thus,

$$\liminf \frac{1}{t} \ln P_{1,1}(t) \ge -(x+\frac 1n).$$

Which implies  $\alpha \le x+\frac 1n$. Since $x$ is any point in the support of $\psi$ and  $n$ is arbitrary, it follows that $\alpha \le \beta$.

On the other hand by $(*)$ we have

$$P_{1,1}(t) = \int_{[\beta,\infty)} e^{-xt} \psi(dx)\le e^{-\beta t} \int_{[\beta,\infty)}\psi(dx) =e^{-\beta t}.$$

Therefore

$$ \alpha \ge \beta.$$

Comment: Thank you so much, I surely need to become more fluent with this kind of arguments. I only underline an $x$ that became $b$ in the domain of integration, anyway thank you again!

Comment: applying $\log$ to both members I obtain $\log P_{11}(t) \geq - (x + \frac{1}{n}) t + \log (\psi ( (x- \frac{1}{n}, x+\frac{1}{n}) \cap [0, \infty) )$ how did you eliminate the part with $\log \psi$?

Comment: divide by $t$, send to $t\to\infty$.